WebSocket failed to connect and tried many ways but still got the problem
My error:
"WebSocket failed to connect. The connection could not be found on the server, either the endpoint may not be a SignalR endpoint, the connection ID is not present on the server, or there is a proxy blocking WebSockets. If you have multiple servers check that sticky sessions are enabled"
I got this problem although i still can connect to server without warning in console log on the website but the error always appears in my terminal when i ran the programme.
My Angular code:
public connect(): void {
    this.hubConnection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
      .withUrl(this.webSockeUrl, {
        transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
        skipNegotiation:true,
        accessTokenFactory: () => { return this.token!},
      })
      .withAutomaticReconnect()
      .build();

    this.hubConnection
      .start()
      .then(() => console.log("Connection started"))
      .catch(err => console.error("Error establishing connection: ", err));
  }

  public addReceiveMessageListener(): void {
    this.hubConnection.on("ReceiveMessage", (message: string) => {
      console.log("Receive Message from server:", message);
    });

    this.hubConnection.on("ReceivePrivateMessage", (message: string) => {
      console.log("Receive Message from another client:", message);
    });
  }

And i still received message from another client through connectionId with this code and authorized normally in Asp.net:
[Authorize]
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string connectionId, string message)
    {
        await Clients.Client(connectionId).SendAsync("ReceivePrivateMessage", message);   
    }

    public override async Task OnConnectedAsync()
    {
        var connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", $"{connectionId} has joined");
    }
}

if i remove skipNegotiation i got negotiation with server incomplete, i also tried add my server port is 44398 to inbound rules of firewall and tried turn window feature "WebSocket protocol" in control panel on. I read many articles involve with this problem and tried but i still can not fix it does not appear in my terminal.
Thanks for help!

There are two JS libraries and two SignalR frameworks in ASP.NET 4.x and ASP.NET Core. Any mismatch will trigger such issues, as the old/new SignalR implementations are incompatible. Can you show what JS library you use from package.json? And on server side are you using ASP.NET Core? Without those, such questions are impossible to discuss.

@angular/animations,
@angular/common,
@angular/compiler,
@angular/core,
@angular/forms,
@angular/platform-browser,
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic,
@angular/platform-server,
@angular/router,
@angular/ssr,
@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome,
@fortawesome/fontawesome-free,
@microsoft/signalr,
bootstrap, bootstrap-grid,
express,
primeicons,
primeng,
rxjs, tslib, zone.js
It's all in my package.json. I'm using signalR in angular for clients and server i'm using asp.net core use signalR (chat hub) for server side


People edit questions to include new information, not in comments. 2) So the JS package seems to be correct. Next you should show the value of this.webSockeUrl, as well as how you launched the ASP.NET Core web app. Too many details are missing there, so people won't understand why port 44398 is involved.


port 44398 because i use it to run asp.net application. My back-end part run at localhost:44398 and this.socketURl is a link connect to websocket with url "https://localhost:44398/chathub". I'm sorry if i reply slowly

Then that error message is expected, as you used the wrong URL. Please review the official sample carefully and see how the correct URL should be determined, https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core/tutorials/signalr-typescript-webpack?view=aspnetcore-8.0
